# MS Access 2007 Inner Join on Same Table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a table t1. It has columns [id] and [id2].

```
Select count(*) from t1 where id=1;
```

returns 31,189 records

```
Select count(*) from t1 where id=2;
```

returns 31,173 records

I want to know the records where id2 is in id=1 but not in id=2.

So, I use the following:

```
Select * from t1 a left join t1 b on a.id2=b.id2
Where a.id=2 And b.id=1
And b.id2 Is Null;
```

It returns zero records. 
Using an inner join to see how many records have id2 in common, I do...

```
Select * from t1 a inner join t1 b on a.id2=b.id2
Where a.id=2 And b.id=1;
```

And that returns 31,060. So where are the extra records in my first query that don't match?
I am sure I must be missing something obvious.

Sample Data

```
id    id2
1     101
1     102
1     103
2     101
2     102
```

My expected results is to find the record with '103' in it. 'id2' not shared.

Thanks for any help.
Jeff

Comment: You want the value of id2 where id = 1??  It's not very clear what you're asking for.  Can you provide a small set of sample data and expected result?

Comment: Thanks Paul. Sample and expected results added above.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to do what is generally called an `exclude join`. This involves doing a `LEFT JOIN` between two tables, then using a `WHERE` clause to only select rows where the right table is null, i.e. there was no record to join.  In this way, you select everything from the left table **except** what exists in the right table.

With this data, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.id2 
FROM test_table t1 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT 
   id, 
   id2 
 FROM test_table 
 WHERE id = 2) t2
ON t2.id2 = t1.id2
WHERE t1.id = 1 
  AND t2.id IS NULL --This is what makes the exclude join happen
```

[And here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcf0a/5) demonstrating this in MySQL 5.7 with the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe Access changes the left join to an inner join when you add a where clause to filter rows (I know SQL Server does this), but if you do the filtering in derived tables it should work:

```
select 
    a.* 
from 
    (select * from t1 where id = 1) a 
left join  
    (select * from t1 where id = 2) b 
on a.id2 = b.id2 
where b.id2 is null
```